# Boost Multiprecision symbols not found during linking with Accumulator

Tags: c++, boost

Hi I'm using Boost Multiprecision libraries with the Boost accumulator. When I'm linking with CMakeLists it's giving me a reference issue

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___gmpf_add", referenced from:
      void boost::multiprecision::backends::eval_add<50u, 50u>(boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<50u>&, boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<50u> const&) in historicQuotePropogationController.cpp.o
  "___gmpf_clear", referenced from:
      boost::multiprecision::backends::detail::gmp_float_imp<50u>::~gmp_float_imp() in historicQuotePropogationController.cpp.o
  "___gmpf_get_prec", referenced from:
      boost::multiprecision::backends::detail::gmp_float_imp<50u>::gmp_float_imp(boost::multiprecision::backends::detail::gmp_float_imp<50u> const&) in historicQuotePropogationController.cpp.o
  "___gmpf_init2", referenced from:
      boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<50u>::gmp_float() in historicQuotePropogationController.cpp.o
      boost::multiprecision::backends::detail::gmp_float_imp<50u>::gmp_float_imp(boost::multiprecision::backends::detail::gmp_float_imp<50u> const&) in historicQuotePropogationController.cpp.o
  "___gmpf_mul", referenced from:
      void boost::multiprecision::backends::eval_multiply<50u, 50u, 50u>(boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<50u>&, boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<50u> const&, boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<50u> const&) in historicQuotePropogationController.cpp.o
  "___gmpf_set", referenced from:
      boost::multiprecision::backends::detail::gmp_float_imp<50u>::gmp_float_imp(boost::multiprecision::backends::detail::gmp_float_imp<50u> const&) in historicQuotePropogationController.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

This is the class I'm using it in

```
    class StatsControllerManager {
    public:
        bool propogateNewStats(Model::Stat stats);
        vector<Model::Stat> propogateNewStats(vector<Model::Stat> stats);
    private:
        void initialize(std::string name, bool backpopulate = false);
        std::unordered_map<std::string, Controller> historicStats;
    };
```

Could anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like boost is using the GMP library have you also linked with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the types used you need

- libgmp
- libmpfr

linked. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/high_precision/use_mpfr.html

These are pretty ubiquitous, but in case you don't want to take the dependency there are the `cpp_`* types (cpp_int, cpp_bin_float, cpp_dec_float) which are pretty much drop-in replacements because all these backends use the same frontend (`number<>`). Again: [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/high_precision.html):

> The last four have some license restrictions; only
> Boost.Multiprecision when using the cpp_float backend can provide an
> unrestricted Boost license.
>
> At present, the price of a free license is slightly lower speed.